# typescript Base type 'xxxx' is referenced before its declaration

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a TypeScript declaration file for CreateJS ( www.createjs.com ).

I have a base class declaration which looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../geom/Point.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../geom/Rectangle.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../geom/Matrix2D.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../filters/Filter.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="Shadow.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="Shape.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="Stage.d.ts"/>

declare module createjs {
  class DisplayObject {

    // constructor:
    constructor();

    ... additional methods

  }
}
```

and then I declare more classes derived from DisplayObject:

```
/// <reference path="DisplayObject.d.ts"/>
declare module createjs {
      class Bitmap extends DisplayObject{
        constructor (imageOrUri:any);

        ... additional methods

      }
    }


   /// <reference path="DisplayObject.d.ts"/>
   declare module createjs {
      class Container extends DisplayObject{
        constructor();

        ... additional methods

      }
    }

    /// <reference path="../../tweenjs/Timeline.d.ts"/>
    /// <reference path="DisplayObject.d.ts"/>
    /// <reference path="Container.d.ts"/>
    declare module createjs {
      class MovieClip extends Container{
        constructor (mode: string, startPosition: number, loop: bool, labels: any);

        ... additional methods

      }
    }
```

etc. etc.

But I'm always getting compiler errors like this:

> Base type 'DisplayObject' is referenced before its declaration
>   or
>   Base type 'Container' is referenced before its declaration.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, everything looks ok.
Any help really appreciated ... many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these two examples in separate files? If so does the second file (declaring the extended classes) have a <reference path..> section pointing to the first?

Comment: All three examples are in separate files. Whole project mirrors CreateJS file structure. At the top of each file I have 'reference paths' to the needed .d.ts files.

Answer (score 5):

If your code is split across multiple files you'll need to let the development tools and the compiler know about the other files using a reference:

```
/// <reference path="createjs.ts" />
```

I have just tested this in Visual Studio and it seems to clear the error, assuming your first code block is in a file called `createjs.ts`, you would add this to the top of your second file.

If they are all in the same file in the order your specified, it all works for me.

**Update**

I have created a Visual Studio project with the following files and it all works - one thing that occurred to me is that you possibly have your code organised into folders, in which case you need to use relative paths such as:

```
/// <reference path="./createjs/DisplayObject.d.ts" />
```

Anyway, here is my working set up in an empty project:

DisplayObject.d.ts

```
declare module createjs {
    class DisplayObject {
        // constructor:
        constructor ();
    }
}
```

Bitmap.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="DisplayObject.d.ts"/>

declare module createjs {
    class Bitmap extends DisplayObject {
        constructor (imageOrUri: any);
    }
}
```

Container.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="DisplayObject.d.ts"/>

declare module createjs {
    class Container extends DisplayObject {
        constructor ();
    }
}
```

And all is happy. You don't need the `export` keyword, because they are all in the same module.

I'm happy to zip this up somewhere if you want to view the example.

Comment: Yes, my code is split across multiple files and I'm using reference paths to the files which classes are needed. I have edited the question ( added reference paths as they are in the code )

Comment: I pasted all classes that derive from the base 'DisplayObject' class into the same file as 'DisplayObject' and all errors are gone ... weird. I really don't have a clue why with separate file it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just spinning up your example in Visual Studio to see what I get.