# TypeScript error TS2449: Class 'x' used before its declaration

Tags: typescript

I don't understand the `tsc` compilation process with respect to`<reference>` and splitting the classes of a namespace across multiple files. I'm using the pattern:

**`src/base.ts`**

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  export class Base {
     /** constructor, etc. */
  }
}
```

**`src/subclass.ts`**

```
/// <reference path="./base.ts" />

namespace MyNameSpace {
  export class Subclass {
     /** constructor, etc. */
  }
}
```

This trivial example works. But as I use the pattern on more files, I periodically get the error `TypeScript error TS2449: Class 'x' used before its declaration.`.

Are we back to manually managing declaration orderings, like `.c`/`.h` files? If so, what tools will help be back track the reference to find the error?

My aim to have a manageable set of files that compile into a single `.js` and `.d.ts` (for another TypeScript library to use). If there a better solution for this scenario? Attempts with variations of Webpack and `import`s have failed me.

If it matters, I'm also using nested namespaces, where the members are defined in subdirectories. I'm always using relative `reference` paths.

This is very similar to [typescript Base type 'xxxx' is referenced before its declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020651), which dealt with a module split across multiple files.

Comment: Have you tried with Modules ?

Comment: I haven't. Per [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) namespaces are preferred. And namespaces align to my desired output: a single global object for my API (the output is client-side `.js` library).

Comment: In Visual Studio Code, this can often be solved by closing down it and reopening it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Major Terminology Alert

Namespaces are *not* preferred over modules. This is a very important point. Let's dive into the history...

Namespaces used to be declared like this:

```
module MyNamespace {

}
```

But they are now declared like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

}
```

*When declaring a namespace*, the `namespace` keyword is preferred to the old `module` keyword.

The reason the `module` keyword was replaced with `namespace` is that people confused them with "modules". You can see where the confusion might come from! Now *actual* [modules (i.e. files that export or import something) are actually a bit better than namespaces](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/), which is why I have spent the entire answer so far covering all this.

## Use Modules

With this in mind, you might consider using modules. Each module gives you a naming context and keeps stuff out of the global scope. You can import and export and everything should work as expected (and you can still bundle it if you like).

*src/base.ts*

```
export class Base {

}
```

*src/subclass.ts*

```
import * as Example from './subclass.ts';

export class Base extends Example.Base {

}
```

## Namespace Merging

If you want to stick with namespaces, you have to respect that everything you place within a namespace (even when that namespace is spread across multiple files) contributes to a single naming context... so you'll have to name the subclass differently.

*src/base.ts*

```
namespace MyNameSpace {
  export class Base {
     /** constructor, etc. */
  }
}
```

*src/subclass.ts*

```
/// <reference path="./base.ts" />

namespace MyNameSpace {
  export class Sub extends Base {
     /** constructor, etc. */
  }
}
```

So ultimately, you can choose modules (proper external modules) where each file has its own naming context, and you can easily avoid naming collisions - or namsepaces where you'll need to be aware that each namespace is a single naming context.

## Small Print

In may examples I have inherited `Base` in the subclass for illustration. You're question didn't exactly do that, but I wanted to illustrate the concept. The question had two classes within the namespace with the same name, which is a duplicate name conflict.

Comment: i had mentioned the same in my comment , as per my understanding typescript encourages modules to be used more

Comment: My choice of Namespaces was to provide a clean API for apps that pull in my `.js` library, and support older browsers without `import`/`export` support. Ultimately, I want a number of functions and classes available to my users in the form of `MyNameSpace.CoolStuff`. Is it possible to do that via modules? All that said, if I continue with namespaces, your answer doesn't give me any help in identifying why I get the error or how to track it down.

Comment: @Amn - based on your question, the issue is attempting to a second class named `Base` within the same namespace. You need unique names for classes when contributing to a single naming context. I covered this above, but I accept there is a lot of answer in there.

Comment: @Fenton All my class names are unique, and I still receive the error. Doh!!!  Just noticed the copy pasta in the original question.  Fixed.

Comment: @Amn - Ah I see... what would I need to add to your trivial example to recreate the error?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this error by **restarting Visual Studio** as mentioned in the comments by @Quentin2

Answer (score 4):

typescript some time work find, some time not, and this error come again.

```js
//file B.ts
class B {}

//file A.ts
class A extends B{}
```

```
error TS2449: Class 'B' used before its declaration.
```

If I change file A.ts to B.ts, A.ts to B.ts, then the problem fixed, haha!

I think it is because A is smaller than B, at ascii, the typescript compiler check them by file name. It is so freak! It's not smart enough :(

Or we must use module....

Comment: Yes, it really works in this way. I've put my derived class-file to sub-directory and its works for me. However I don't know how would work this approach from package for example.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes to this same answer and is working with Visual Studio Professional (mine is version 2019), vsprof seems not smart enough to know in what order to compile the files in some cases, if that happens you can change the compilation order by editing the file .csproj by putting them in the order that allows them to be compiled (the extended class before the extender one) in "ItemGroup" "<TypeScriptCompile ... " section.

This does not guarantee that the error will not appear again if vsprof decides to change the order again (although it has not happened to me, I know it can happen).

So although this can be a temporary solution, you would do better thinking about start using modules.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the namespace and managed the order of "compilation" between the files, I succeeded using a reference file.

In your *.ts files you reference a "*.d.ts" file. ex.: app.d.ts

In this "*.d.ts" file you reference the files of your program, in the order you need.

''' lang-js
//file A.ts

///

...
your code
...

'''

'''
//file b.ts

/// 
...
your code
...

'''
''' lang-js

// file app.d.ts

/// 
///

'''