# Typescript - Set Object property value with new Class()

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I've created a Class that represents properties of an element:

```
export class ElementProperties {
    constructor(
        public value: string,
        public adminConsentRequired: boolean,
        public displayString?: string,
        public description?: string){}

}
```

Then I'm creating an Object the same has as in normal Javascript:

```
static readonly MyObject = {
        ChildProperty1: {
            NestedPropA: new ElementProperties(
                "My value",
                true
            ),
            NestedPropB: new ElementProperties(
                "My value in B",
                false
            )
        },
        ChildProperty2: {
            ...
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the error:

`Class 'ElementProperties' used before its declaration.ts(2449)`

I have dozens of those ElementProperties object initialization and doesn't make sense to be creating variables for each one.

Any ideas how to go around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to look for that error? read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680616/typescript-error-ts2449-class-x-used-before-its-declaration) about it, it might help.

Comment: @OmriAttiya I did, but all I can find is GitHub issues of people complaining about it without any real explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb but I found the answer.

Forgot that Typescript is sensitive to declaration order in a file.

`MyObject` was in a another class at the same file, with ElementProperties class declared at the end.
Changing the order so the ElementProperties class so its declared first fixed the issue.